# Extract lines containing a string from a file into another file without using strstr

Tags: c, string

So if `input.txt` is:

```
abd123
123gy
dhakf
hu123
```

and target string is `"123"`

I need the `result.txt` to be:

```
abd123
123gy
hu123
```

I would use something like

```
while(fscanf(fp1, target, ...) != 0)
      fputs(target, fp2);
```

I have to do this without using functions of `string.h`.

Comment: First of all you want to [read full lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Secondly you want to [check if the string contains the wanted sub-string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr). And if it does you you print the line.

Comment: Use `fgets` and `strstr`

Comment: @4386427 can you show me how to to this without using strstr

Comment: You are obviously searching for a `strstr` implementation. Why? What did you try in *that* direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `getline` to read every line of the file and use `strstr` to check if it contains the line that you are looking for. That should be enough to go off, good luck :)

Comment: is there a way to do this without using strstr

Comment: @shay I suppose you will have to roll your own function for checking if a string contains a sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `line` it is probably better to use fgets:

```
char line[100];
char target[100] = "123";
while(fgets(line, 100, input_file))
   if(strstr(line, target)) // don't forget to #include <string.h>
       fputs(line, output_file);
```

Here is a function to check if `source` contains `target`:

```
int strstr(char *source, char *target)
{
    int j, k;
    for(int i = 0; source[i]; ++i) //each time it start searching from a different position in source
    {
        for(j = 0, k = i; target[j] && source[k] == target[j]; ++j)
            ++k;

        if(!target[j]) //if there was a match then index j will be the '\0' of target
           return 1;
    }
    return 0; // If it gets here it means that no matches were found from any starting point.
}
```

Comment: I can't use strstr. I am not allowed to use string.h

Comment: oh, then you should code something that implements strstr behavior

Comment: @shay When will you start showing us *that* code?

Comment: I wouldn't call this function `strstr` because the return values differ from the [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) in `string.h`; a better name would by `hasstr` or `contains_str`...